# Hide public access to directories but allow through RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following structure:

```
public_html/
  hidden_directory/
    sub_folder/
      sample_file.txt
      other_file.txt
    another_folder/
      another_file.txt
```

My end goal is to have the contents of `hidden_directory` visible only through redirects.  My first attempt at putting them outside the `public_html` was unsuccessful.  Then I tried the structure you see above with a Redirect like

```
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*) hidden_directory/sub_folder/$1 [L]
```

to access through:

```
http://mysite/sub/sample_file.txt
```

And that worked great giving me the content I wanted from the file location and URL I wanted.  But I didn't like that files were also available from:

```
http://mysite/hidden_directory/sub_folder/sample_file.txt
```

I did do a

```
deny from all
```

in `hidden_directory`, and that stopped direct access like I wanted, though it also broke the rewrites.

Is there any htaccess solution that I could have these files in a folder not directly accessible yet still reachable with rewrites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any htaccess solution that I could have these files in a folder not directly accessible yet still reachable with rewrites?

Yes use a rule based on `THE_REQUEST` variable to block direct access to `hidden_directory`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block direct access to a given path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+hidden_directory[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ hidden_directory/sub_folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!